# properties of integrals to show value lies on interval

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I use the properties of integrals to show value of integral lies on interval [0,1]. Integral x^2 arctan(x) dx from 0 to 1. 
I know how to get the integral but I'm not sure how I would prove that it lies on the interval.
Thank You!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Given any $x\in [0,1]$, the function $x^2\arctan(x)$ is also bounded in $[0,1]$.

Hence by the property of integration, 
$$
\int_0^1 0dx \leq \int_0^1 x^2\arctan(x)dx \leq 
\int_0^1 1 dx
$$

Solving the two integrals (from left to right, the first one and the last one) gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems a bit ambiguous. If I understand correctly, you can show the integral is less than one by showing the maximum of the integrand in [0,1] is less than 1, resulting in an area less than 1. See the picture below.

[image]