# Use properties of integrals to show the value of a definite integral lies on a specific interval?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question says to "Use the properties of the integrals to show that the value of the integral $\int_0^1x^2tan^{-1}x\ dx$ lies on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{12}].$"

I said that because this function is positive on [0,1] (which was part of part a of this question), the integral will be positive. However, I don't know how to explain that the integral will be less than $\frac{\pi}{12}$. I found the below question, but I don't know if the highest rated answer helps me because it seems like it relies on the fact that the interval of integration is the same as the interval they are proving this statement for.

[properties of integrals to show value lies on interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243482/properties-of-integrals-to-show-value-lies-on-interval)

I calculated the integral and it does indeed lie within this interval, but I expect the question doesn't want me to just state that.

Comment: On $[0,1]$, $0\le x^2 \tan^{-1} x\le x^2\cdot{\pi\over 4}$; so, your integral is at most $\int_0^1{\pi\over 4} x^2\,dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we need to do now is to show that the integral is at most $\pi/12$. Let's do an integration by parts:
$$ \int_0^1x^2\tan^{-1}(x)\;dx=\left.\frac13x^3\tan^{-1}(x)\right]_{x=0}^1-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}dx=\frac\pi{12}-\frac13\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}dx. $$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. I can proceed from there yes. I wasn't sure if that's what they were looking for, but it seems simple and explanatory.